# Clip fixed/absolute elements with a scrollable div

Tags: css

I'm attempting to have several overlapping divs that are then selectively displayed through scrolling. This can already be accomplished with images using `background-attachment: fixed`, but I'm looking for a solution that can work with any child element.

A working example of the desired effect with images:

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.scroll-block {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<html class="overflow-hidden">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/tailwind.css">
</head>

<body class="main">
  <div class="scroll-block" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/500/500)">
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-block" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/400/400)">
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-block" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/300/300)">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried simply putting a fixed/absolute div inside the scrollable blocks and setting `overflow: hidden`, but the overflow property has no effect on fixed/absolute divs. Is there any way to achieve this with CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clip-path` can help you here:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.scroll-block {
  height: 100vh;
  clip-path: inset(0);
}

.scroll-block > *  {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align:center;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<body class="main">
  <div class="scroll-block">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300">
      <h2>title1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-block">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400">
      <h2>title 2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-block">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300">
      <h2>title 2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I was unaware that `clip-path` would work if positioned on the relative element; thank you!